# Access instance by Value in LinkedList

Tags: c#, class, linked-list

I have a class like this:

```
public class foo {
    int par1;
    int par2;
}
```

I've also a foo type linked list :

```
public static LinkedList<foo> fooList = new LinkedList<foo>();
```

I want to access this class by Value:

```
fooList.Find(???);
```

What can I place instead of ??? for Value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99a4073e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will take a `T` (in your case a `foo`) and use its equality method (in your case reference equality—the same object—because you are creating a `class`) to determine equality.

If you want to find by some other definition of equality (eg. the contents of a member) then you can use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var found = fooList.First(f => f.par1 == 1);
```

to get the first match (or throw if none found). Use [`FirstOfDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to return `null` instead if not found.

Comment: Nice and short expaqnation of what the FindI() method does.

Answer (score 0):

If "by value" you mean an instance of `foo`, then just pass an instance of `foo`.

```
foo foo1 = new foo();
foo foo2 = new foo();
foo foo3 = new foo();

var linkedList = new LinkedList<foo>(new[] {foo1, foo2, foo3});

LinkedListNode<foo> node = linkedList.Find(foo2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq:

```
foo item = fooList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.par1 == 201);
```

If you are going to use a lot of objects, consider using a dictionary:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, foo>();
dict.Add(201, new foo(){par1 = 201, par2 = 567});
// ... add a lot of foo objects   
foo item = dict[201];
```

(This example shows how to find foo objects by the par1 value)